# Boolean Logic question: can I coerce these 4 if statements into a single boolean statement?

Tags: c#, boolean-logic

I have a boolean logic question. I have the following if statements that should be able to be coalesced into a single boolean expression. Please help. I've spent way too much time on this and I'm actually too ashamed to ask my co-workers.

```
if (denyAll == true & allowOne == false) return false;
if (denyAll == true & allowOne == true) return true;
if (denyAll == false & allowOne == false) return false;
if (denyAll == false & allowOne == true) return true;
return true; //should never get here
```

I'm sure there is an elegant solution.

Thanks

Comment: any reason why you're using bitwise?

Comment: With `bool` it's actually just non-short-circuiting. (And there's not really a good reason to use it here.)

Comment: yeah that's what I meant to say

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Would `return allowOne;` do the trick?

Comment: Ahahahahahahaha - awesome.  Wish I'd got there first.

Comment: fantastic, of course the answer is obvious, it was in front of me the whole time. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I think it's just:

```
return allowOne;
```

The denyAll value doesn't seem to matter:

```
denyAll   allowOne   result
false     false      false
false     true       true
true      false      false
true      true       true
```

Answer (score 2):

To supplement the other answers, some basic tips:

you can use `if (allowOne)` instead of `if (allowOne == true)` or `if (!allowOne)` instead of `if (allowOne == false)`

Also, with conditional operations, you should typically use the `&&` operator instead of `&`, as this allows short-circuiting. For example in the expression `if (denyAll && !allowOne)`, if `denyAll` is false, it will not bother evaluating `!allowOne` since the expression is already false.

Furthermore, if your method is returning a `bool` as it is here, then you can often simplify the expression into the return statement itself. For example this:

```
if (!denyAll && allowOne)
   return true;
else
   return false;
```

simplifies to this:

```
return (!denyAll && allowOne);
```

Comment: I typically use condensed formatting (forget the == true) as well as short-circuit-ers, but I wanted the question to be clear. However, thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

How about `return allowOne;`. If everything is just a variable and reading has no side effects, then that should have the same result.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the value that really matters is your "allowOne" bool (since it doesn't seem to matter what denyAlls value is). Assuming that, you van just check if allowOne is true.

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as I can see:

```
If allowOne = true then return true;
return false;
```

would do it the "Deny all" setting doesnt seem to have any effect on the outcome and should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
if (denyAll && !allowOne) 
    return false;
return denyAll || allowOne;
```

Nevertheless you should consider something that is more readable.

Update:
As some others have pointed out (and what I haven't seen) is, that you actually ignore denyAll all, so `return allowOne;` is all you need.